# Yolov5 model on SR300 camera from turtlebot2i

Tags: python, ros, yolov5

I have build my own model of recognition using yolov5 and it's working but i'm having trouble using it on the image_raw topic from the camera_sr300/rgb, on github I already checked a few made code but the version where not up to date because of my latest yolov5 version model's.
Do you have a way to solve my problem ?

Comment: There needs to be more details here. Just saying you're having trouble using a topic doesn't help much. What specific trouble or errors are you getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.